# why there is aliasing when play the model

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the unity to show some meshes, but I found the effect is not good as there seems a lot of aliasing on the object. How to improve?[image]

Comment: Use Posteffects on Camera, or for more realistic aliasings, go to Assetstore.

Comment: I don't personally know much about unity but you might  find the [quality settings doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html) to be useful. I assume there is some way to apply them to the renderer in the unity editor. Beyond that there does appear to be custom aa implementations on the asset store but as far as I can see the only free one is fxaa so that might not be super useful.